# asp.net mvc route with parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, routes

I am trying to get the following links:

- / (maps to `AccountController` / `Index`)
- /account/login (maps to `AccountController` / `Login`)
- /2112/emails (maps to `EmailsController` / `Index` action and 2112 would be a route parameter)
- /2112/emails/list (maps to `EmailsController` / `List` action and 212 would be a route parameter)

I am not being able to get the routes working as they seem to be conflicting with each other. The following makes me have the route param at all times which is not what I need. It will not bind without providing the database param.

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{database}/{controller}/{action}",
    defaults: new { database = UrlParameter.Optional, controller = "Account", action = "Index" }
);
```

Comment: `routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default_with_hidden_index",
                url: "{controller}",
                defaults: new { action = "Index" },
                constraints: new { action = "Index" }
                );


            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Account", action = "Login" }
                );`
This will solve the first and second topics I asked but not the other two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Order is important in your route config. The key to routing in MVC is to start with the most specific routes and work up. Also as you have specific routing rules for the Emails controller, you can give the name of the controller specifically in the URL parameter. So here you would do this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Emails",
    url: "{id}/Emails/{action}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Emails", action = "Index" },
    constraints: new { id = @"\d+" }
);

routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Account", action = "Index" }
);
```

Comment: He may also want an id in the default route, so I would think about adding a constraint for the id to be a number in the emails route

Comment: @DanielJ.G. It's possible, but we can't tell from the question text. I noticed a typo anyway so added it in while I was fixing that.

Comment: Thanks for the help. It works 100% for what I asked.